# Data binding to Listbox from JSON Response

Tags: c#, json, listbox

This is the first time i am doing xaml so please understand that I might be slow in learning

Below is my CS codes. I am trying to bind the "attributes" to listbox.

```
public DirectionPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        List<Feature> features = App.dResult.directions[0].features;
        foreach (Feature f in features)
        {
            Attributes a = f.attributes;
            MessageBox.Show(a.text);
        }
    }

    public ObservableCollection<Feature> test = new ObservableCollection<Feature>();
```

Below is the XAML codes.

```
 <ListBox x:Name="directionListBox" ItemsSource="{Binding}" >
            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding text}" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextTitle2Style}" />
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ListBox>
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Paste your code as a **text**, not as an **image**..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didn't see the collection of attributes.
Possibly what you can do is collect the attributes in a list may be your `test` and put it in the biding.

Or put the Features collection as itemsource of your list box.
i.e.

```
public DirectionPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        List<Attributes> LAtributes=new List<Attributes>();
        List<Feature> features = App.dResult.directions[0].features;

        foreach (Feature f in features)
        {
            Attributes a=new Attributes();
            a = f.attributes;
            LAttributes.add(a);
            MessageBox.Show(a.text);
        }
       directionListBox.ItemsSource=Lattribute;
    }
```

and

```
<ListBox x:Name="directionListBox" ItemsSource="{Binding}" >
            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=text}" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextTitle2Style}" />
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ListBox>
```

Hopefully this will help you!

Comment: The thing is what type attribute in features is? As I am looking it it has also property called text.
So collect first attribute with a list, may be like the following
List<Attributes> attributelist=new List<Attributes>();
then collect in for loop you created by adding
attributelist.add(f.attributes); and
directionListBox.ItemsSource=attributelist;
after all in the xaml
ItemSource={Binding Path text}// in this case I am considering text as a property of class Attributes.

Comment: currently, i am trying to bind the attribute in list box and display 'text' in the list box. text is a method in attribute class

Comment: So that is fine!
Just collect the attribute objects in a collection. and assign the collection list box item source.
In the biding use the method name 'text'
Eg. if the collection of attributes is 'Lattribute' then directionListBox.ItemsSource=Lattribute;

then on xaml just bind like ItemSource="{Binding}" and in the templete of TextBlock use Text="{Binding path=text}"
hope this will help you